# Rasterio mask washing out result

Tags: qgis, python, rasterio, masking

Using the `rio.mask.mask` function to clip out a section of an ortho. The result `.tif` looks like it has been "washed" out. The pixel values from the ortho and the result are exactly the same, so seems like QGIS is reading it oddly? I set the symbology of both layers to exactly the same settings and still same issue. Process works on other orthos I have. Only difference is that this ortho has a projection of `ESRI:102057` and my orthos that do work have a projection of `EPSG:3857`. Any additional information I can give?

```
def crop_ortho2(poly, ortho_dir, output_dir):
    with rio.open(ortho_dir) as src:
        shapefile = fiona.open(poly, 'r')
        shapes = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]
        out_image, out_transform = rio.mask.mask(src, shapes, crop=True)
        out_meta = src.meta
        print(out_meta)
        out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                         "height": out_image.shape[1],
                         "width": out_image.shape[2],
                         "transform": out_transform})
        output = output_dir + "0.tif"
        with rio.open(output, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
            dest.write(out_image)
            dest.close()     
        shapefile.close()
    src.close()
```

**meta**

```
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'uint8', 'nodata': 0.0, 'width': 16809, 'height': 23231, 'count': 4, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(6339), 'transform': Affine(0.15, 0.0, 535020.9,
       0.0, -0.15, 4882392.3)}
```

**Ortho**
[image]

**Result**
[image]

Comment: It looks like your fourth band (near IR?) could be getting interpreted as alpha / transparency.  Maybe try setting the `ALPHA=unspecified` gtiff creation option?

Comment: Interesting... I thought I was just handling RGB, but it does look like there is a near IR band. I'll have to check with the src acquisition about that. Let me get back to you on that and EXCELLENT discovery/idea!

Comment: @mikewatt that worked beautifully! Thank you for teaching me something! Please post your answer!

Comment: Awesome.  Will do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be caused by the fourth band being interpreted as alpha / transparency.  If that's the case, setting the `ALPHA=unspecified` geotiff [creation option](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#creation-options) will tell the viewing software to ignore it instead.